# Video recording with Edge using HTML5

Tags: html, html5-video, microsoft-edge, web-mediarecorder

I am trying to record video using HTML5 API. I want this solution to be cross platform and it should atleast work on Chrome, Firefox and Edge browser. I tried with following code

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: true,
  video: true
}).then((mediaStream) => {

  const video = document.querySelector('video');
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
  video.src = url;
});
```

Above code displays video in Chrome and Edge. When I try to capture bytes using MediaRecorder API, it only works in Chrome and not in Edge. Please suggest what can be done.

```
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
recorder.ondataavailable = onDataAvailable
...
function onDataAvailable(d){
   //d.data is populated in Chrome but not in Edge.
}
```

Please suggest, how can I capture bytes so that it can be saved on server.

I tried [MediaStreamRecorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder) but that too didn't work with Edge.

**Update** : I found few approaches which indicate use of Canvas as an option to render frames and capture the bytes. Then use requestAnimationFrame to continue capturing video. While this might work, I am still open to any other better suggestions.

Comment: So first don't use `URL.createObjectURL` with a MediaStream, instead set the `srcObject` of your MediaElement directly to the MediaStream. Now, Edge doesn't support the MediaRecorder API (it's [*under consideration*](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/?q=mediarecorder)  though), so it's a no-go.

Comment: The only way would be to draw the video frames on a canvas, to export each frame as a standalone image, to use the Web Audio API in order to extract the raw PCM data of your audio track, and finally to repack everything in a video format. I don't believe this can be done in real time, and it would probably take longer for you to develop this than to wait IE implements this API.

Comment: Did you have any luck? I'm currently up against this myself but not really getting much headway in how to tackle it (I don't even care if it's an Edge-specific implementation)

Comment: Hi @Peter Mellet, I couldn't get a reliable solution for Edge. There have been suggestions to fallback on ORTC or webRTC for Edge browser and record stream using media servers like kurento. While I could able to record video, the quality of video was a big question due to variable bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

The MediaRecorder API seem to be only implemented in FireFox & Chrome

https://caniuse.com/#search=MediaRecorder

I'd always check caniuse.com for browser support for new APIs!

Comment: Hi Zouhir, Thanks for your reply. But it doesn't answer my question. I am aware of caniuse website. What I am looking for is the reliable way of video recording in Edge.